# Extract urls from given string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
house home go https://www.monstermmorpg.com
nice hospital http://www.monstermmorpg.com 
this is incorrect url http://www.monstermmorpg.commerged 
continue
```

I want to extract all the urls that starts with http/https

I do try using this regex but i get nothing.

```
$('links').value = stringText.match("\b(?:http://|https://)\S+\b/");
```

Comment: just place `.*?` at start and at the end of your pattern
`".*?\b(?:http://|https://)\S+\b/.*?"`

Comment: Here's it "working": http://jsfiddle.net/PTFBt/ . At least it's a start

Comment: And by the way, to find `http` or `https`, you can use: `https?:\/\/` instead of your "or" with `|`

Comment: Anyone can explain why `http://www.monstermmorpg.commerged` is incorrect?

Comment: @Tommi I'm thinking because it doesn't end with a "valid" top level domain. But at the same time, who knows what these URLs are, and what the possible top level domain possibilities are

Comment: I don't believe that validation of top-level domain is possible with regex. There are many of them, and 1 (.museum) is long enough; also your intranet admin can do local domain even longer, so invalidate domain by length is wrong.

Comment: @Tommi There's no need to tell me. I'm not the OP, I was just trying to answer your question, which I really don't have an answer for.

Comment: Sure. I talking not personally to you, I think OP read comments as well.

Comment: @user2463937 It does "work", but you need to explain better what you expect to happen. Here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/PTFBt/2/

Comment: I want to extract the urls, but i get is Null instead.

Comment: Sorry, with the last one it worked, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var string = "house home go https://www.monstermmorpg.com hospital "
     +" http://www.monstermmorpg.io"
     +" this is incorrect url http://www.monstermmorpg.commerged"
    .match(/\b(https?:\/\/.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)/g);
```

// only the first two.

```
   ["https://www.monstermmorpg.com", "http://www.monstermmorpg.io"]
```

Comment: I would love an explenation so I can fix it downvoters

Comment: I did not downvote you, anyway, this  <jsfiddle.net/PTFBt/2> did the trick for me. thank you for your help.

Comment: You get www.monstermmorpg.commerged on that fiddle

Comment: Yeah i noticed, I will use your regex to avoid that problem, thanks a lot.